# What's a way to read a specific line from a text file?

Tags: c#

I want to read a line from a text file, except that I want to specify the line to read.

I've tried:

> using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Program Files\TTVB\Users.txt"))
>
> ```
>             {
>                 text = reader.ReadLine(acctMade);
>             }
> ```

acctMade is an int.

This returns:

> No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllLines` (which will give you an array), and then access the line via the correct array index.  `string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(); string desiredLine = text[acctMade];`

Comment: How big is the file ?

Comment: Only a few kilobytes. Tim, ReadAllLines doesn't exist.

Comment: @Minicl55 - I edited my comment to `File.ReadAllLines` - to do this you'll need to use `File` instead of `StreamReader`.  See [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

Comment: If you do end up with a large file, you could seek to the end of the file then read backwards until you find a newline(depending on character set) then read that to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is not that big, you can use **[`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)** to put the file into a array of strings:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Program Files\TTVB\Users.txt");
Console.WriteLine(lines[acctMade]);
```

You need to use `using System.IO;` at the top of your code or use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` in order for it to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

A variety of ways:
[Read certain line in a text file (CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12159/Read-a-certain-line-in-a-text-file)

A simple way using StreamReader:

```
string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
{
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
       for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
          sr.ReadLine();
       return sr.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Snippet from: [How do I read a specified line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262965/how-do-i-read-a-specified-line-in-a-text-file)

For a more efficient but complex way:

- [Efficient way to read a specific line number of a file. (BONUS: Python Manual Misprint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589327/efficient-way-to-read-a-specific-line-number-of-a-file-bonus-python-manual-mi)